# Error al llamar a función en MySQL: Data truncation

Tags: java, sql, funciones

He creado una función en MySQL para hacer un SELECT de un campo de una tabla y al llamarla desde un programa Java, cuando le paso el parametro de entrada, me da el error: 
Data truncation: Data too long for column 'tlf' at row 1

Función de MySQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION paciente_tlf(d int) RETURNS VARCHAR(9) BEGIN DECLARE tlf VARCHAR(9); SET tlf = 'INEXISTENTE'; SELECT telefono INTO tlf FROM pacientes WHERE NSS=d; RETURN tlf; END;
```

Función de Java para llamar a la función de MySQL:

```
public static void funcion(Scanner teclado, Connection conexion) {
    try {

        String sql = "{ ? = call paciente_tlf(?)}";
        System.out.println("Dime ID de paciente para ver su teléfono: ");
        int id = teclado.nextInt();

        CallableStatement llamada = conexion.prepareCall(sql);
        llamada.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
        llamada.setInt(2, id);

            llamada.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Telefono del cliente con ID " + id + ": " + llamada.getString(1));


        llamada.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Dejo una imagen de la tabla de SQL.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Soy yo o estas tratando de setear "Inexistente" un campo de 11 caracteres en un varchar de 9?

Comment: Ay Dios, estoy ciego, no me había fijado! Muchas gracias.

Comment: No hay de que, a todos nos ha de pasar en algún momento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un varchar tiene una capacidad fija y máxima que tu has establecido previamente, en este caso de 9, con lo que no puedes intentar guardar valores de mayor capacidad.